# Python 3: String validation (password)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Individually, these statements work (I've made individual helper functions) and I've compiled them onto one function. How am I able to get them to work together? Additionally, how would I make this program run without module 're'? It works but I got it off someone else on this site. These are what I need in this program:

- Has to have a number
- Characters in the beginning and end of the string have to be letters
- Must be between 10 and 20 characters
- There can't be 3 characters in a row
- Previous password can't be used again

Here is my code:

```
import re 
def password_validator (pw_v, prev_p): #pw_v = string that is to be validated; prev_p = previously used strings in a list

    prev_P = [s]
    # do I use 'while True' instead of returning True statements every time?
    if 10 <= len(s) <=20:
        return True
    elif s[0] and s[-1].isalpha():
        return True 
    elif not re.search('(.)\\1{2}', s): # How else can I write this without using 're'?
        return True
    elif any(digit.isdigit() for digit in s):
        return True
    else: 
        return False
```

Comment: You can use or's to organize your code a little better.

Comment: Note that the return statement means exit from the function, so in this case if any of the condition matches, it will return True.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code checks if the input satisfies only one of the conditions.

Note that when you `return`, the function returns and ignores the rest of the code. Considering this fact, you can use either:

(1) Nested `if`s

```
if 10 <= len(s) <= 20:
    if s[0] and s[-1].isalpha():
        # the rest of the conditions
            return True    # all of the conditions were met
return False    # one of the conditions wasn’t met
```

(2) Return `false` when one the first condition isn't met (which actually uses [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)).

```
if not 10 <= len(s) <= 20:
    return False
if not s[0] and s[-1].isalpha():
    return False 
# the rest of the conditions
```

Regarding the regex use, in my opinion it's elegant in this case; but you can always switch to a loop that iterates over the input's characters, combined with a counter of repeated characters (which isn't as elegant):

```
def three_identical_characters(input):
    counter = 0
    for i in range(1, len(input)):
        counter += (1 if (input[i] == input[i-1]) else 0)
        if counter == 2:
            return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 1):

Store each of the conditions results in a variable, e.g. has_correct_length and has_digit.

Combine them:

```
has_correct_length = (10 <= len(s) <=20)
has_digit = any(digit.isdigit() for digit in s)
fulfills_restrictions = has_correct_length and has_digit
```

This way your code is much easier to read and documents itself.

Answer (score -1):

You don't test if the condition is met, you test if the condition is not met:

```
import re 
def password_validator (pw_v, prev_p): #pw_v = string that is to be validated; prev_p = previously used strings in a list

    prev_P = [s]
    # do I use 'while True' instead of returning True statements every time?
    if not 10 <= len(s) <=20:
        return False
    elif not (s[0] and s[-1].isalpha()):
        return False
    elif re.search('(.)\\1{2}', s): # How else can I write this without using 're'?
        return False
    elif not any(digit.isdigit() for digit in s):
        return False
    else: 
        return True
```